# Knockout mapping grid with dynamic adding of items not behaving

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I have a nice knockout viewmodel with a list that is shown as a grid.
I do use the mapping plugin.

You can select items, reverse selection, remove items from the list and dynamically add items.

But if i do add an item, I can't remove it or any other items.
Also if I add another one it does not show.
But a computed value does show extra lines

Here is the fiddle isolating the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/medo/7jrnb/

```
self.add = function () {
    self.orderLines.push(ko.mapping.fromJS({ Sku: "", Qty: 1, Name: "", OriginalSKU: "", Description: "", Exists: false, Selected:false }));
```

};

delete and select items, all is well.
Press add item and deleting does not work.
pressing add again is also an unexpected result.

knockout-2.2.1.js
Knockout Mapping plugin v2.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `add` function, you misspelled `OriginalSku` as `OriginalSKU` (different case).  This causes the binding to fail and, it appears, to stop knockout from working.  Fix your spelling and you're all set.